# Generate the link to create new document using SharePoint online template

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have a SharePoint Online site running the Communication template. Members can create new document by clicking on the New button in the document library then select the relevant template. For example, we have a Project Plan template which is an Excel file. See below for more info

[SharePoint New Document screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z0YX.png)

Currently, our members have to browse to the document library then click on the New button and select the template.  Is it possible to generate a link to trigger the creation of a new document using a particular template? This will help to eliminiate training for staff

Answer (score 1):

Can you please have a try below link?

```
<a href="ms-word:nft|u|{template url}|s|{save file location}"><h2>New Document</h2></a>
```

Example:

```
<a href="ms-word:nft|u|https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/testdoclib/Forms/CTName/tem.docx|s|https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/testdoclib"><h2>New Document</h2></a>
```

More reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. Unfortunately not what i am looking for. I am hoping to open the document in Excel Online not Excel. So the template is located at https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/improvement/Project Plans/Forms/New Project Plan.xlsx. I want to obtain a hyperlink that create a new document using this template and save the file at https://rfdsvictoria.sharepoint.com/sites/improvement/Project Plans while opening the new document in Excel Online. Is that possible?